# How can I set current date in a property of an object in XML v1.0 using Spring-objects?

Tags: c#, spring, date, properties, spring.net

This my current code which works fine  for set the dates but I want to set the current date as default how can I get this value?
It's possibly to use system.DateTime.Now  as a class of an object for get it?

```
<object type="Date" singleton="false">
       <property name="StartDate" value="2000-01-01" />
 </object>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the expression language (SpEL) inside the xml instead of value to call system types.

```
<object type="Date" singleton="false">
   <property name="StartDate" expression="DateTime.Today" />
</object>
```